# Lua: How to multiply -- efficiently -- all elements in a 1-dimensional table consisting of numbers

Tags: algorithm, lua, multiplication

Suppose that we have a Lua table called `t`, defined as follows:

```
t = {4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Suppose we wish further to know what the product of the numbers in `t` is. (Aside: the answer is `840`.) I can think of two methods.

First, a basic `for` loop:

```
answer = 1
for i = 1, #t do
   answer = answer * t[i]
end
print ( answer )
```

Second, an `ipairs` iterator:

```
answer = 1 
for i, j in ipairs ( t ) do
   answer = answer * j
end
print ( answer )
```

(I suppose one could also use a `pairs` iterator.)

My questions:

- Does either of the two methods shown above suffer from any real drawbacks?
- Are there methods for obtaining the desired value of `answer` that are more efficient and/or robust than the methods shown above?

Comment: print(840) is the most efficient way

Comment: @JasonGoemaat - Thanks. My question wasn't about how to print out a known number. It was about how to perform the multiplication of all elements in a Lua table that's known to consist of numbers, preferably in an efficient way. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ipairs` involves a function call. This makes generic for-loop slower tiny bit. If the inner task is anything complex, the function call overhead will be negligible, in comparison to a few arithmetic operations it may be notable in some extreme cases. Try it:

```
a={} 
for i=1,2e8 do a[i]=math.random() end
t=os.time()
q=1
for i=1,#a do q=q*a[i] end 
print(os.time()-t)
w=1
t=os.time()
for i,v in ipairs(a) do w=w*v end
print(os.time()-t)
```

For me results were `15` and `18`. 
It is more impactful when the calculation is repeated multiple times (nested loops):

```
a={} for i=1,1e4 do a[i]=math.random() end
t=os.time() q=1; for i=1,1e5 do for j=1,1e4 do q=q*a[j] end end print(os.time()-t)
t=os.time() q=1; for i=1,1e5 do for _,v in ipairs(a) do q=q*v end end print(os.time()-t)
```

But still not a lot.

If you really need to squeeze out even that bit of performance, you probably should take a look at [luajit](http://luajit.org/) and various numeric frameworks based on it: [1](http://scilua.org/), [2](http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/), [3](http://torch.ch/).
Also, there's [article](http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf) on optimization by the language author.